# Python/Beautiful Soup – finding string within heading within div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Being new to Python I spend about an hour trying to find a string with Python 2.7.x and Beautiful Soup from a heading inside a div:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = urllib2.Request("http://somerandomurl.org")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
```

The HTML file looks like this:

```
<div class="ABC">
    <h1>My string</h1>
</div>
```

I can't describe all the ways from the [Beautiful Soup Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) I tried here (including `print soup.div('ABC').h1` …), but I assume I got something terrible wrong while reading. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanted:

```
soup.find('div', class_='ABC').h1
```

which would find the *first* `div` tag with the `ABC` class, then traverse to the first H1 tag inside of it:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''
... <div class="ABC">
...     <h1>My string</h1>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> soup.find('div', class_='ABC').h1
<h1>My string</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you. In my example this gives me the following error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'h1'"

Comment: @lejonet8: then you do *not* have a div with that class in your input HTML.

Comment: <div class="ABC">
           <h1>
            XYZ
           </h1> The original class name contains a - might this be a problem?

Comment: @lejonet8: does `soup.find('div')` return anything? Does `soup.find(class_='ABC')` match anything? You need to narrow this down. No, a dash (`-`) in the class name does not make a difference.

Comment: It works, the problem was sitting in front of the computer. Thank you again.

Comment: Martijn, please allow one additional question concerning the soup.find approach: When class slightly chances in different documents (e.g. `ABC1`, `ABC2` oder `ABC3`), is there a possibility to work with this using BeautifulSoup options? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can use a regular expression to match the class; `import re` then `.find('div', class_=re.compile(r'ABC\d'))` would match all those.